# Can a recreation center ban me without reason and not reimburse my fees?

Tags: canada, harassment

I took a martial arts class at a recreation center. It ended 3 months ago. Today I received a phone call from the director of the recreation center. He asked me to come in for a meeting regarding multiple complaints about my behavior. He refused to discuss it over the phone or give me any more detail. I am taking other classes at the same recreation center (for example I use the gym) and he asked me not to attend until we've had our in person meeting. I was sincerely unaware of any issues or incidences that happened.

What are my legal rights? My understanding is since it's a private building they can ban me from it for no reason. Would they have to reimburse me for the membership and class fees that I'm currently enrolled in? Do they need a valid reason to ban me?

Comment: We cannot advise what you should or should not do. Indeed that does not belong in a question here. But it is fine to ask what your legal rights are, or what the law permits. You will probably get a better answer if the jurisdiction (country, state, province)  is specified.

Comment: As currently written, this does not ask for specific legal advice, and should not be closed on that basis.

Answer (score 4):

### What does the contract say?

When you signed on for these classes, you signed a contract. This will spell out each party’s rights and obligations. Since the rec centre drafted the contract it probably gives them the right to expel you and probably doesn’t require them to reimburse you if they do; but you would need to read it to be sure.

Comment: @user47428 What does the **contract** say?