# Not sure if it's worth hiring a lawyer because not sure if what happened was illegal

Tags: privacy, canada, lawyer, british-columbia, libel

Something recently happened to me that I'm not sure was legal. To give a high level overview I was accused of something I didn't do. An internal investigation found me guilty. The investigation was unfair and they banned me, but to my understanding this isn't technically illegal. They wrote a report that I think would be libel *if* they shared it with other people. Is this something a lawyer could help with or would it be a waste of effort?

Comment: If you want to know if something might be illegal, consulting a lawyer is the best option. Be aware that the question might not have a definite answer. A lawyer can also advice on avenues of legal actions, probabilities of success, risks and costs/benefits.

Comment: What is your concern exactly, that the report might get shared? Smells like potential defamation, so if you think the risk is high it might be worth getting a lawyer to send them a cease and desist letter.

Comment: @Greendrake this happened at a recreation center that is part of  large university. If I apply for classes or a job (in another department) could they share this report? That is my question, who can they legally share this report with?

Comment: @Roland, your comment misunderstands the purpose of Law SE. If you want to know if an action is illegal, asking in general terms on SE is exactly the right thing to do. If you want to get specific legal advice with the intent of acting on it, *then* you should hire a lawyer. Asking for knowledge is why SE exists.

Comment: Either way, you need to make up your mind sooner rather than later as statutes of limitations can bar claims later.

Answer (score 1):

In British Columbia, there is an [Access Pro Bono lawyer referral service](https://www.accessprobono.ca/our-programs/lawyer-referral-service) where they connect you with a lawyer who would provide a free 15 minute consultation.

They tell you whether they think they would be helpful and help you understand what legal needs you might have.

You should also read [this question and answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/85557/can-a-recreation-center-ban-me-without-reason-and-not-reimburse-my-fees), which seems to address your comment that "they banned me, but to my understanding this isn't technically illegal." However, do not rely on anything you read on this site.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is worth the cost: First, a lawyer can tell you whether what happened to you was legal or illegal, so then you know. Second, whether it was legal or illegal, a lawyer can tell you whether you can do something about it or not. Third, a lawyer can take action. This may range from a well written letter signed by a lawyer that has a chance of changing someone’s mind (very cost effective) to wasting thousands on a case without any chance to win.

Worst case, you might regret for the rest of your life that you didn’t fight back. If you pay a lawyer just for him or her to tell you “sorry mate, what happened to you is unfair, but you have zero chance of winning a case”, that will remove that regret and be worth it for you.